# Shell wildcard with parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a green hand in Shell. Please see my following code. How to make it working?

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls {*.txt,*.exe}
a.txt  b.txt  a.exe b.exe
[root@localhost ~]# filter={*.txt,*.exe}
[root@localhost ~]# echo $filter
{*.txt,*.exe}
[root@localhost ~]# ls $filter
ls: {*.txt,*.exe}: No such file or directory
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Which shell? They're all different.

Comment: As an aside, that looks like a root prompt. Being logged in as root while experimenting is universally considered a really bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
eval ls $filter
```

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** Assuming Bash and Linux here in absence of any concrete information.

First of all you can get this via `find`, e.g.

```
find -type f -name '*.sql'
```

... or `echo`:

```
echo *.{sql,log}
```

as well. Many ways to do one thing in *nix shells :)

Secondly you'd have to `eval` the expression to make use of the globbing feature (globbing is the technical term for wildcard expansion).

You'll also want to enclose the assignment in single quotes to avoid expansion to happen too early:

```
filter='*.{sql,log}'
```

then observe:

```
$ echo $filter
*.{sql,log}
```

but:

```
$ eval "echo $filter"
test.sql test.log
```